# Looking for partial in wrong location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Maybe it's my brain taking some time to warm up after the long weekend but my head is about to explode. I'm trying to include a shared partial, which I have in

```
/app/views/shared/_invitee_fields.html.erb
```

In my main page view /app/views/pages/_form.html.erb I'm including the partial like so:

```
<%# Render the partial of the invitee fields. %>
<%= render :partial => "/shared/invitee_fields", :locals => { :form_builder => i } %>
```

However, this results in an error being thrown, for a missing partial, apparently looking in the wrong location.

```
Missing partial pages/invitee_fields, application/invitee_fields with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.
```

It's as if the framework is ignoring my explicite choice to look in /shared and falling back to the convention. I'm sure that I'm making some form of glaringly obvious mistake, but I can't spot it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: That should be fine.   Check elsewhere in the file for your code to add a new field, it is likely render :partial => "invitee_fields" or something similar.

Comment: Hi Shawn - yeah I thought it should be fine - it's most odd. Stranger still, if I delete the file /app/view/shared/_invitee_fields.html.erb than I get an error: Missing partial /shared/invitee_fields

Comment: right, the partial is being loaded somewhere else too (most likely in your dynamic add_invitee_field)   check there.

Comment: Hang about - you may be right, I have a helper method in my main template further down the page which might be looking in the wrong location.

Comment: Yep - you were spot on - a little more digging into that helper method and sure enough there is a render statement in there.